# Binary Sum Complexity

Tags: recursion, binary

I am having problem with the calculation complexity of this method. I think at each call, number of operations is doubling and that is why I say it O(2^n) but answer says that it is O(n). Can you explain how could it be so?

```
int binarySum(int[] d, int low, int high){
if(low > high)
   return 0; 
else if( low == high)
   return d[low];
else{
int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;
return binarySum(d, low, mid) + binarySum(d, mid+1, high);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the number of operations is doubling in every step, **but there are also only log n steps before the entire array is added**. If there are 16 elements in the array, for example, it only takes 4 "steps" to go through every element in the array. Thus, the number of operations is 2^4 or 16.

Thus, the complexity is not really 2^n, but rather 2^log n which is just equal to O(n).